# Whats wrong with my code?(changing pictures using javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

I want the picture to change from bulb off to bulb on on the clicks of the two buttons.I have seen a similar example in W3schools, however, I can't see the difference between the codes. Please help.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
function light(switch){
    var pi;
    if(switch == 0){
        pi = "pic_bulboff.gif"
    }
<!--this is if the switch value is zero-->
    else{
        pi = "pic_bulbon.gif"
    }
<!--this is if switch value is anything else including 1-->
    document.getElementById('sw').src = pi;
}
</script>

<img id="sw" src="pic_bulboff.gif">

<button onclick="light(0)">Light off</button>
<button onclick="light(1)">Light on</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `switch` is a [*reserved keyword*](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/reserved-keywords) which can not be used as argument name

```js
function light(s) { //Change argument name
  var pi;
  if (s == 0) {
    pi = "pic_bulboff.gif";
  } else {
    pi = "pic_bulbon.gif";
  }
  document.getElementById('sw').src = pi;
  document.getElementById('sw').title = pi; //Just to demonstrate
}
```

```html
<img id="sw" src="pic_bulboff.gif">

<button onclick="light(0)">Light off</button>
<button onclick="light(1)">Light on</button>
```